# Is it possible to centre each row / tr in a table?

Tags: html, css, html-table, center

I am trying to centre each rows (`<tr>`) of a `table`.
I have an uneven number on a couple of rows.

Here is an example of my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

At the moment the output is as shown below:

[image]

But I would like it to be like so:

[image]

If this can be achieved I would be very happy to know how it can be done.

Comment: 1) do you really need a table here ?  2) display will do anything

Comment: Should this need a table only solution ?

Comment: If no table tag is required, flexbox is a modern and easy solution to achieve your desired layout.

Comment: No CSS at the moment, purely HTML, if it can be achieved in a table it would be good but I am open to any other solutions

Comment: @w0ns88, a div based solution would be much easier here.

Comment: With pure HTML and no CSS - I don't think it'll be possible. @w0ns88 better solution will be fexbox.

Comment: @CharanKumar I meant I am not using CSS at the moment but most probably will have to. What would a solution in flexbox be like? Never used it.

Comment: If you want to do that layout, probably semantically is not a table, then, better not to use a table

Comment: 2selector and 3 rules(including flex and min-width) can do the visual, but this is definitely not a table A table is build  from datas that are to be read/match from columns and rows , here the visual is not coherent with the meaning of a table datas layout

Comment: @GCyrillus I get what you mean, so how should I get the output wanted with display rather than table?

Comment: can i use the css for this???

Comment: you may just turn your table  tags into regular tag , and keep this structure

Answer (score 6, accepted):

example with regular tag (same structure)

```css
div {
  display:table;
  border:solid 1px;
  margin:auto;
  }
p {
  margin:0;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  }
span {
  margin:3px;
  min-width:1em;
  border:solid 1px;;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    <span> 1 </span>
    <span> 2 </span>
    <span> 3 </span>
    <span> 4 </span>
    <span> 5 </span>
    <span> 6 </span>
    </p>
  <p>
    <span> 7 </span>
    <span> 8 </span>
    <span> 9 </span>
    <span> 10 </span>
    <span> 11</span>
    </p>
  </div>
```

**for INFOS only** . the CSS for your table would be :

```
tr {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}
td {
  min-width:1.5em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<table width="652" height="120" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="646" height="57"><table width="649" height="55" border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="baseline"><table width="528" height="55" border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way by nesting tables too. I increased the padding and spacing for a better view.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
  .inside_table td{
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  .table_out{
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
 .table_out td{
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <table class="table_out" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10">
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6" style="border:none">
        <table class="inside_table" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10">
          <tr>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>11</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using **flexbox**. You can specify the number of columns for each row using CSS.

Read more about flexbox [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
div.wrapper {
  width: 240px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  padding: 3px;
}
div.wrapper div {
  border: 2px solid grey;
  width: calc((100% - (5px * 2 * 6)) / 6);
  /* 6 - Number of columns in a row */
  /* 5px - 3px margin + 2px border width */
  margin: 3px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
    <div>10</div>
    <div>11</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks will look into it!